# Ajax - How to submit one by one input value - Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Sorry for my english is not so good. And i'm newbie :)

I want to update one-by-one input value with ajax in Codeigniter, but it not work right.. only one save button (one form) work, others form not work .. please help me edit below code

Here's the demo code:

**View:**

```
<script>
   $(function(){
       $(".submit45").click(function(){

         dataString = $("#prod_upd").serialize();
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?=PREFIX?>admin/update/change_ppx3/",
           data: dataString,
           success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
               document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML=data;
           }
         }); 
         return false;  

      });
   });
</script>

<?$i=0;if(count($PPX) > 0)foreach($PPX as $item){$i++;?> 
<form name="prod_upd" id="prod_upd" method="post" >
        <input type="text" name="p_ppx" id="p_ppx" size="8" value="<?= number_format($item['p_ppx'],0,'','')?>" class="i_ppx">
        <input type="hidden" name="ids_p" id="ids_p" size="8" value="<?=$item['id']?>" class="i_ppx">
        <input type="button" name="sub" id="sub" class="submit45" value="Save4" />
        <div id="dd" style="float: left;">hello</div>
</form>
    <?}else{?>                                   
    <div class="no_data">Nothing here</div>
<?}?>
```

**Controller:**

```
function change_ppx3(){
    $id_p = $_POST['ids_p'];
    $rs = $this->ppx->get_ppx_by_id($id_p);
    $ppx_value = $_POST['p_ppx'];

    $this->ppx->update_ppx(array("id"=>$id_p),array("ppx_r"=>$ppx_value));        

    if($_POST['p_ppx']):
        echo "done: ";
        print_r($_POST['ids_p']);
        echo "-";
        print_r($_POST['p_ppx']);
        return true;

    endif;

    }
```

Comment: What are the errors you getting?

Comment: hi Ronak, problem is only one save button (one form) work, others form not work, and how to submit value one by one with multi form like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because every form has the same id="prod_upd".

test this

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $(".prod_upd").submit(function(){

     var $this = $(this), dataString = $this.serialize();

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?=PREFIX?>admin/update/change_ppx3/",
       data: dataString,
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
           $this.find('.dd').html(data);
       }
     }); 
     return false;  

  });
});
</script>

<?$i=0;if(count($PPX) > 0)foreach($PPX as $item){$i++;?> 
<form name="prod_upd" class="prod_upd" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="p_ppx" size="8" value="<?= number_format($item['p_ppx'],0,'','')?>" class="i_ppx">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids_p" size="8" value="<?=$item['id']?>" class="i_ppx">
    <input type="submit" class="submit45" value="Save4" />
    <div class="dd" style="float: left;">hello</div>
</form>
<?}else{?>                                   
<div class="no_data">Nothing here</div>
<?}?>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it work great now with simple php test code, but  in my project: First form (first input value) not work when i click save button.. it's reload page, what's wrong with my js

Comment: if error is only for the first form, then somethings wrong when $i=0. _or_ take help of the browser's javascript console. add a error function to your [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)